# What is the better way to call consecutive web service android?

Tags: java, android, web-services

In app, I am calling multiple web service consecutively.For instance, user gets login first and on successful call, I call 'Check Available' service on that successful call I call 'Download Web service' on getting response successfully then I further do other things.Happens what on Log in successful call if internet interrupts or server stops responding I show a message (internet interrupt/ server not responding). I want to continue or resume process as soon as internet gets connected (means it should keep retrying). For this I am catching exception SocketTimeOut and other exception and in finally I am checking if exception occurred, giving call back to calling class and in call back method I am calling webservice again after pausing thread for 5 seconds(To void calls frequently). My question what should be better approach for this sequence calls of webservice. As I have implemented it is better?

Comment: code more code , please

Answer (score 0):

I think you should listen for changes in connectivity rather than trying every 5 seconds.  The phone could be offline for hours.

Somewhere such as application `onCreate`:

```
registerReceiver(
      new ConnectivityChangeReceiver(),
      new IntentFilter(
            ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

In another class:

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver
               extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      debugIntent(intent, "grokkingandroid");
   }

   private void debugIntent(Intent intent, String tag) {
      Log.v(tag, "action: " + intent.getAction());
      Log.v(tag, "component: " + intent.getComponent());
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
      if (extras != null) {
         for (String key: extras.keySet()) {
            Log.v(tag, "key [" + key + "]: " +
               extras.get(key));
            // Do whatever you need based on connectivity status
            // You could send an internal broadcast that your web service code listens for
         }
      }
      else {
         Log.v(tag, "no extras");
      }
   }

}
```

Taken from:
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-getting-notified-of-connectivity-changes/

There are plenty of resources on this topic.